# volume of a spherical sector of a 4-sphere

Tags: geometry, spheres

How does one calculate the volume of a spherical sector of a 4-sphere?

In 3-dimensions, this is $V=\frac{2 \pi r^2 h}{3}$, where $h$ denotes the height of the cap.

Comment: How the 4 sphere intersect (I assume you want a section that is part of all of them). Where are the centers? On same plan? Radios on surface?

Answer (score 0):

This paper

> Li, Shengqiao. "Concise formulas for the area and volume of a hyperspherical cap." *Asian Journal of Mathematics and Statistics* 4.1 (2011): 66-70.
>   [Journal link](http://www.scialert.net/fulltext/?doi=ajms.2011.66.70&org=11).

reaches an equation for the volume of a hyperspherical cap in $\mathbb{R}^2$:

---

[image]

---

See the paper to interpret the notation.