# Volume of a spherical segment in high dimensions

Tags: geometry, volume, spheres, monte-carlo, geometric-probability

Consider 2 **parallel** hyperplanes of the type

$0 \leq \langle w,x \rangle + b$ and $\langle w,x \rangle + b < c$ where $x, w \in \mathbb{R}^n ; b,c \in \mathbb{R}$

cutting an $n$-ball with radius $r$ and centered at origin, $||x||_2 \leq r$.

Hence, the volume of intersection of the 2 hyperplanes forms a [spherical segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_segment).

- What is the volume of the intersection in closed form? (or an upper-bound for that matter)
- Is it possible to get a closed form using sampling? If yes, can I have some guidance please?
- Is there some other way to look at this rather than a spherical segment? probably as the difference in volumes of spherical caps?

Comment: Is this of any help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2391568/volume-of-a-spherical-sector-of-a-4-sphere/2392746#2392746  [see the journal link in the given answer]

Comment: @boojum thanks. Using this I am getting the difference between incomplete beta distribution with different colaltitude angles as the result. But there is no closed form for the distribution, hence I am stuck. Do you have any suggestions on how I can do this using sampling by any chance?

Comment: Random sampling in an $n$-ball is somewhat tricky. Why not just use ordinary numeric methods of integration? The integral seems reasonably well-behaved. This is just a guess, but I guess that any desired level of accuracy could be achieved much more easily by deterministic methods than by Monte Carlo.